# Isomorphism between quternian and SU(2) and their homomorphisms to SO(3)

Tags: representation-theory, rotations, quaternions, linear-groups, general-linear-group

From Kostrikin, A. I. (1982). Introduction to Algebra. Springer-Verlag,

$$\Gamma: \operatorname{SP}(1)\subset\mathbb{H} \to \operatorname{SU}(2)$$
$$a+bi+cj+dk \mapsto 
\left(\begin{matrix}
a+bi    &  c+di \\
-(c-di) & a-bi \\
\end{matrix}\right),$$
is an isomorphism.
And respectively, they can induce rotations in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ by $\Phi$ and $\psi$:

$$\Phi_g=H^{-1}\circ\varphi_g\circ H: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3, g \in \operatorname{SU}(2);$$
$$\psi_p: \mathbb H^- \to \mathbb H^-, p \in \operatorname{SP}(1),$$
$$p \mapsto pqp^{-1}$$
where
$$ H: \mathbb R^3 \to M_2^+$$
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto \left(
\begin{matrix}
z & x+iy \\
x-iy & -z\\
\end{matrix}
\right);$$
$$ \varphi_g: M \mapsto gMg^{-1}$$
and $\mathbb H^-$ is the pure quaternion subspace of $\mathbb H$, which can be seen equal to $\mathbb R^3$.

My question arises here:

According to my calculation, for example, if we pick $q = \sin(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) + k \cos(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) \in \mathbb H$, then
$$\Phi_q = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)& 0 \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$
but $$\Gamma(q) = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) & i\sin(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) \\ i\sin(\dfrac{\theta}{2}) & \cos(\dfrac{\theta}{2})  \\
 \end{matrix} \right)$$ thus
$$\psi_{\Gamma(q)} = \left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{matrix} \right) \neq \Phi_q.$$

Is my calculation wrong or are the $\Phi$ and $\psi$ not good inductions or is $\Gamma$  not a good isomorphism so that $q$ and $\Gamma(q)$ is the same rotation in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$?

Thank you.

--*update*--

I find that
$$ \Gamma (q):
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a+di & c+bi \\
-c+bi & a-di
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
should do the right isomorphic.

Comment: I have not checked your version of the matrix representation of quaternions as this is secondary. The [basic facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions) are: The unit quaternion $q=a+bi+cj+dk$ rotates (by conjugation $qpq^{-1}$) the pure quaternion $p$ (i.e. the vector from $\mathbb R^3$) around the ***axis*** $(b,c,d)$ and by the angle $\theta$ given by $a=\cos(\theta/2)\,.$ This should enable you to check your calculations.

Comment: Thank you.
And the quaternion parts seems right and natural, since $q= \cos\theta + \vec e_i\sin\theta \in \mathbb H$, it gives a rotation over axis $\vec e_i$.
$\vec e_i\in\{i,j,k\}\subset \operatorname{SP}(1)$